How to Ensure Email Template Compatibility Across Different Email Clients, I am using Nodemailer, ejs in a Node.js Application?
Context:
I'm working on a Node.js backend application using the MERN stack with TypeScript. I use Nodemailer for sending emails, and I initially used EJS for my email templates. However, I encountered formatting issues in various email clients (e.g., Gmail displays correctly, but web.de and GMX do not).
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ticket Returned to LoCo</title>
    <style>
        body {
            min-width: 100;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 1.5;
            color: #222222;
        }
        .container {
            max-width: 600px;
        }
        p {
            color: #000000;
        }
        .message {
            white-space: pre-line;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <% if (message) { %>
            <p class="message"><%= message %></p>
        <% } %>
        <% if (signature) { %>
            <img src="<%= signature %>" alt="Signature" style="max-width: 60%;">
        <% } %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

import nodemailer, { Transporter } from 'nodemailer';
import ejs from 'ejs';
import path from 'path';
import juice from 'juice';

type Attachment = string | Express.Multer.File;

export interface EmailOptions {
    email: string | undefined;
    subject: string;
    template: string;
    data: { [key: string]: any };
    attachments?: Attachment[];
    cc: string[];
    bcc: string[];
}

export interface TransportOptions {
    host: string;
    port: number;
    service: string;
    secure: boolean;
    auth: {
        user: string;
        pass: string;
    };
}

const sendMail = async (options: EmailOptions, transportOptions?: TransportOptions): Promise<string> => {
    const transporter: Transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(transportOptions || {
        host: process.env.SMTP_HOST,
        port: parseInt(process.env.SMTP_PORT!),
        service: process.env.SMTP_SERVICE,
        secure: process.env.SMTP_SECURE === 'false',
        auth: {
            user: process.env.SMTP_MAIL,
            pass: process.env.SMTP_PASSWORD
        },
    });

    const { email, subject, template, data, attachments, cc, bcc } = options;
    
    const templatePath = path.join(__dirname, "../template/mails", template);
    const templatePathOptional = path.join(__dirname, "../template/mails", "locomail.ejs");

    const html: string = await ejs.renderFile(templatePath, data);
    const inlinedHtml = juice(html);

    console.log("juice-html", inlinedHtml);
    
    const htmlOptional: string = await ejs.renderFile(templatePathOptional, { email, subject, data, cc, bcc });

    const mailOptions = {
        from: process.env.SMTP_MAIL,
        to: email,
        cc: cc,
        bcc: bcc,
        subject,
        html: inlinedHtml,
        attachments: attachments ? attachments.map(attachment => typeof attachment === 'string' ? { path: attachment } : {
            filename: attachment.originalname,
            content: attachment.buffer,
            contentType: attachment.mimetype
        }) : []
    };

    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
    return htmlOptional;
};

export default sendMail;


Whether or not the email looks consistent across clients has nothing to do with the templating engine you used to make it and everything to do with the resulting template that was outputted. Also "formatting issues" is not an adequate problem description. Formatting issues could mean anything from "the font is different" to "images aren't displaying" to "this div should be next to the other one but it's actually over/under it". It would be useful to (a) strip out all the JS code and provide the rendered HTML output and (b) show the formatting issues in some way
